# How to delete a tree node and its childs records from a table (without cascade delete)?

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, tree, sql-delete

I have this table in postgreSQL v9.1:

```
CREATE TABLE ad_treenodemm
(
  ad_tree_id numeric(10,0) NOT NULL,
  node_id numeric(10,0) NOT NULL,
  ad_client_id numeric(10,0) NOT NULL,
  ad_org_id numeric(10,0) NOT NULL,
  name character varying(60) NOT NULL,
  isactive character(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'Y'::bpchar,
  created timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  createdby numeric(10,0) NOT NULL,
  updated timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  updatedby numeric(10,0) NOT NULL,
  parent_id numeric(10,0),
  seqno numeric(10,0),
  CONSTRAINT ad_treenodemm_pkey PRIMARY KEY (ad_tree_id , node_id ),
  CONSTRAINT adtree_adtreenodemm FOREIGN KEY (ad_tree_id)
      REFERENCES adempiere.ad_tree (ad_tree_id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE DEFERRABLE INITIALLY DEFERRED,
  CONSTRAINT ad_treenodemm_isactive_check CHECK (isactive = ANY (ARRAY['Y'::bpchar, 'N'::bpchar]))
)
```

Important columns description:
* ad_tree_id = The tree group id (connected to ad_tree table)
* node_id    = The node id
* parent_id  = The parent node id (if 0 => means the node is on the top)

The rests of columns can be ignored.

For example, I have the ad_treenodemm table data presentation like this:

```
# Group1 (all node belows are assigned with ad_tree_id=1001)
    -Accounting (node_id=101, parent_id=0)
        -Costing (node_id=202, parent_id=101)
            -Cost Type (node_id=103, parent_id=202)
            -Cost Element (node_id=24, parent_id=202)
        -Client Accounting Processor (node_id=105, parent_id=101)
        -Reset Accounting (node_id=6, parent_id=101)
            ...

    -Finance (node_id=4110, parent_id=0)
        ...

# Group2 (all node belows are assigned with ad_tree_id=1002)
    ...
```

Let's say, I want to delete **Accounting** node and its child nodes in the Group1. That means, it also deletes node: Costing, Cost Type, Cost Element, Reset Accounting,...etc. How to do it?

The solution can be in SQL or Java language with JDBC (but SQL would be preferred if possible).

**UPDATE:**
I found a solution with WITH RECURSIVE (CTE) sql, however it's not too elegant:

```
WITH RECURSIVE temp(ad_tree_id, node_id, parent_id) AS (
    SELECT a.ad_tree_id, a.node_id, a.parent_id
    FROM ad_treenodemm a 
    WHERE ad_tree_id=1001 AND node_id=101      -- look at this

    UNION ALL

    SELECT b.ad_tree_id, b.node_id, b.parent_id
    FROM ad_treenodemm b
    INNER JOIN temp c on c.node_id = b.parent_id
    WHERE b.ad_tree_id=c.ad_tree_id
)
DELETE FROM ad_treenodemm a
WHERE (a.ad_tree_id, a.node_id) IN (
    SELECT ad_tree_id, node_id FROM temp
);
```

You see that I put the argument ( WHERE ad_tree_id=1001 AND node_id=101) inside the WITH clause. Anyone know how to improve the SQL by putting the argument statement outside the WITH clause?

For anyone who want to experiment the query without deleting the records, use this:

```
WITH RECURSIVE temp(ad_tree_id, node_id, parent_id) AS (
    SELECT a.ad_tree_id, a.node_id, a.parent_id
    FROM ad_treenodemm a 
    WHERE ad_tree_id=1001 AND node_id=101

    UNION ALL

    SELECT b.ad_tree_id, b.node_id, b.parent_id
    FROM ad_treenodemm b
    INNER JOIN temp c on c.node_id = b.parent_id
    WHERE b.ad_tree_id=c.ad_tree_id
)
SELECT * FROM ad_treenodemm a
WHERE (a.ad_tree_id, a.node_id) IN (
    SELECT ad_tree_id, node_id FROM temp
)
ORDER BY a.parent_id, a.node_id
```

Comment: Why not put an `ON DELETE CASCADE` foreign key on `parent_id`? This seems to be a perfect use case for it.

Comment: @lc: this is a table from an open source application. It's not made by me, I'm afraid if I alter the table structure, the application will break when updating to new version. But anyway, I'm interested, so could you tell me how to add ON DELETE CASCADE to the parent_id and the delete query solution?

Comment: I tried to add foreign key constraint (parent_id) reference to same table (node_id), however it's failed because node_id is not unique and it turned out that the table's primary key is composite (ad_tree_id, node_id). So is there a way to make foreign key refers to composite primary key?

Comment: @suuid If I understand your schema correctly: `FOREIGN KEY (ad_tree_id, parent_id) REFERENCES ad_treenodemm(ad_tree_id, node_id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE`

Comment: @suuid This is an ideal case for a recursive common table expression (Recursive CTE, or `WITH RECURSIVE`). See http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html

Comment: @CraigRinger: when I tried your sql (the foreign key constraint), it's failed with this error message: DETAIL:  Key (ad_tree_id, parent_id)=(10, 0) is not present in table "ad_treenodemm".

Comment: @suud I was showing you the *syntax* of how to create multi-column keys, I don't know if the *logic* is right because that's specific to your application. So either I misunderstood the relationships or the tree contains nodes that have missing parents. Someone might've tried to be clever and give the root node a `parent_id` of a non-existent node 0, in which case you can't use a foreign key constraint because the root node has a missing parent and the constraint can not be satisfied.

Comment: @Craig: it's indeed there is a record that the parent_id is NULL (empty value), however in application logic, it's treated as 0 value. But, I read in documentation, as long we don't use MATCH FULL option in the constraint, isn't it'll be alright? Meanwhile, I'm trying the WITH RECURSIVE (CTE), but still can't get the query right.

Comment: Here is good article (http://www.slideshare.net/quipo/trees-in-the-database-advanced-data-structures) about storing trees in databases. It contains SQL samples for basic CRUD operations in different types of trees. Another way is to use CTE to select all nodes that belong to a tree branch and delete them.

Comment: @suud If the parent has NULL `parent_id` then it should be fine, yeah. That means you must have an invalid row in there or have misunderstood the data structure and defined the foreign key wrong, because the row with ad_tree_id=10 and parent_id=0 is referenced by another row, but doesn't actually exist.

Comment: @Craig: I think it raised error because 0 and NULL are not considered same in SQL, perhaps. To Konstantin: thx for the article, I will read it in spare time. To all: please look at the OP, I had added the WITH RECURSIVE (CTE) solution, but it's still a bit imperfect.

Comment: @suud: `NULL` is explicitly *not the same as anything*. `NULL` isn't even the same as `NULL`. Whenever you compare anything to `NULL`, the result is `NULL`. You need to understand that or you will be lost in database wonderland.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter: thx. So I guess in this case, the WITH RECURSIVE query is a better solution than to adding ON DELETE CASCADE constraint.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Adding a FK constraint would qualify as "altering the table structure". Since you don't want that, we are down to a [**recursive query**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html) or a function doing the work recursively.

Without such restrictions, the most elegant solution would be to fix the `null` values you mentioned and add a [`NOT NULL` constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-NOT-NULL) to the column. *Then* add the [FK constraint](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK) with `ON DELETE CASCADE` as mentioned in comments, first by [lc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/44853/lc).

#### Recursive query

`DELETE` with a "writeable" CTE:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE x AS (
   SELECT ad_tree_id, node_id
   FROM   ad_treenodemm
   WHERE (ad_tree_id, node_id) = (1,5)  -- enter dead node walking here

   UNION  ALL
   SELECT a.ad_tree_id, a.node_id
   FROM   x
   JOIN   ad_treenodemm a ON a.parent_id = x.node_id
   )
DELETE FROM ad_treenodemm a
USING  x
WHERE (a.ad_tree_id, a.node_id)
    = (x.ad_tree_id, x.node_id);
```

[Data-modifying CTEs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) require PostgreSQL 9.1 or later. Else you have to run a separate `SELECT` to collect the rows and then `DELETE`.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/cNf2OZgt)
<sub>Old [sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c5e44/1)</sub>

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it looks cooler than mine :). So the "dead node" must exist inside the WITH clause? Why x doesn't has (..., ...) parameters and what is USING mean?

Comment: @suud: Column names for CTEs are optional. If you don't spell them out, names of the `SELECT` items are used. `USING` is PostgreSQL's way to join in tables to a `DELETE` statement. Consult the manual for details [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-delete.html).